# ExpatError: no element found - Python script

Tags: python, elementtree, expat-parser

Using OS X 10.6.8, libxml 2-2.7.8, libxslt-1.1.26, and python 2.6, I'm trying to run the tumblrRestore.py script linked here:

https://github.com/hughsaunders/Tumblr-Restore/blob/master/tumblrRestore.py

It ran successfully and restored 76 posts before crashing.

However on second run I got an ExpatError: no element found, and have not been able to run it successfully since - it always produces this same error now. Error text:

```
Tumblr Restore
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tumblrRestore.py", line 264, in <module>
cli.start()
File "tumblrRestore.py", line 232, in start
bp.parse()
File "tumblrRestore.py", line 51, in parse
postelement=ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 964, in XM
return parser.close()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1254, in close
self._parser.Parse("", 1) # end of data
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

I'm wondering whether I have the wrong or competing or outdated versions of python or lxml, though that still doesn't explain why the script ran successfully once.

Complete newbie, any advice appreciated.

Comment: check the encoding of your file. maybe you have a BOM mark or something ugly in it. The error message sounds like it is not happy with the very first character in `xml_string`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried receiving as Unicode UTF-8 no BOM, but am still getting exactly the same error. Also I'm still wondering why it ran correctly the first time but won't on subsequent occurrences?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `extract_xml_string` method of `BackupParser` class. It definitely returns empty string, because your `begin_re` regular expresssion doesn't match xml header.

Try the next one:

```
begin_re = re.compile("<\? xml .*\?>")
```